# Can this be written as a single SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables in 2 separate databases.

Table 1 has user information I need to retrieve via a stored procedure.

Table 2 (in `db2`) has a foreign key to the user id in table 1. But there can be many rows of data in this table per user.

I want to retrieve just the oldest record from this table.

i.e.

```
db1.dbo.userProfile
id int
... 


db2.dbo.userRecords
id int
fk_userProfile int
DateCreated DateTime
.....
```

and as an example if my data was

```
table 1
id otherData
1  ...

table 2
id fk_userProfile oldestDate otherData
1         1       10/10/2012  ....
2         1       09/10/2012  ....
3         2       10/10/2012  ....
4         1       03/03/2013  ....
```

I want to get out for user 1

```
id = 1, profiledata, 10/10/2012
```

this is what I initially tried, but it is returning the top 1 user, I need to get it for all users. In addition, there is no guarantee that the oldest date is the first record back.

```
SELECT TOP 1 LastDate as RenewalDate, u.* 
FROM db2.dbo.ActionDates AS uad 
INNER JOIN Users AS u ON uad.UserId = u.Id
WHERE u.shopId = @shop
```

I have got this working on 2 stored procedures, where in my code I get all users for a shop, then loop over all the users and do a select on the other table that does a top 1 after selecting and ordering, but if I have 50 users for a shop, then that's 51 queries.

So can I do this in one select, or do I need to do it in stages and use a temp table?

Comment: why are your query columns/tables different than your sample data? do you want lastdate from userrecord or actiondates table?

Comment: Apologies, db is on other pc, so I was having to copy and edit to remove spurious information. I want the lastdate from the actiondates table

Comment: your data and expected results do not match your query, is there any id column in actiondates table?

Comment: Apologies for the bad copy / translate between machines, but @rs you still managed to solve my issue. Next time I'll just c n p from the source machine and database to make life easier for you all. Thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

For your sample data and result use this

```
;with CTE as
(
select * , row_number() over (parition by up.id order by ud.id) rn
from userprofile up
inner join userrcord ud on up.id = ud.fk_userProfile
)

select * from cte where rn = 1
```

To get first row for each user, your example query should be:

```
;with CTE as
(

SELECT LastDate as RenewalDate, u.* , 
row_number() over (parition by userid order by lastdate) rn
-- replace order by lastdate with order by ActionDates.id if you store any id
FROM db2.dbo.ActionDates AS uad 
INNER JOIN Users AS u ON uad.UserId = u.Id
WHERE u.shopId = @shop

)

select * from cte where rn = 1
```